# Independent Variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be set of random variables. Suppose we know that $X\perp Y$ and $X\perp Z$, my question is: is $X\perp Y\cup Z$? i.e., does the following holds for any $x,y,z$?

$$\Pr(x,y,z) = \Pr(x)\Pr(y,z)\quad\forall x,y,z,$$

Any simple proof would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. X,Y,Z are random variables but you treat them like events. 2. Line 2 refers to Union but your equation has Intersection.

Comment: Here the union means the union of random variables, and I think it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following joint distribution of the three random variables:

```
X Y Z Prob
0 0 0  1/4
0 1 1  1/4
1 0 1  1/4
1 1 0  1/4
```

You with find that $X$ is independent of $Y$, and $X$ is independent of $Z$, but $X$ is not independent of $Y$ and $Z$ together: indeed it is determined by $X= Y\text{ XOR }Z$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the great example given here!